# How to remove foreign escaped quotes from string? Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have parsed an HTML file and extracted text using Beautiful Soup, but some of the text grabbed has likely incorrect quotes (different font or character, etc.), so in the JSON file I print out to, I am seeing escaped quotes. I have tried to replace them with empty strings, but since they are not compatible quotes with the ones I type from my keyboard, I don't think they are being recognised as quotes in my replace() function, which means the replace function is not working. I also tried to declare my replacement as a raw string by putting a little 'r' in front of what I wanted to replace, but it made no difference. How do I remove the escaped quotes?

Code:

```
'tag': div.text.split(',', 1)[0].replace('\n', '').replace('\u00a0', ' ').replace(r'\"', ''), # remove chars ',', ' \n', and '\u00a0',
```

JSON:

```
{
    "tag": "\"Data Scientists You May Know\" suggester",
    "definition": "",
    "source": [
        {
            "title": "Data Scientists You May Know",
            "URL": "https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/data-science-from/9781492041122/ch01.html#RSdata01"
        },
        {
            "title": "Data Scientists You May Know",
            "URL": "https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/data-science-from/9781492041122/ch01.html#idm45635773432952"
        }
    ]
},
```

As you can see, the tag name is `"\"Data Scientists You May Know\" suggester"`, when it should be just `"Data Scientists You May Know suggester"`.

Comment: You do not want `r'\"'`  The string does not actually contain a backslash, it just contains a quote.  The JSON has a backslash because of the outer quotes.  You just want `.replace('"','')`.

Comment: Those are "smart quotes", Unicode `'\u201c'` and `'\u201d'`.

Comment: @TimRoberts unfortunately, `.replace('"', '')` did not remove anything.

Comment: @tromgy interesting. Would it be possible to change them to unicode then call a replace() function on them?

Comment: just do `replace('\u201c', '').replace('\u201d', '')` instead of `replace(r'\"', '')` to remove them

Comment: @tromgy thanks that worked! If you wanted to create an answer for it, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the website in question renders like this:

[image: Screenshot of the site]

Those curly quotes point different ways for opening and closing, they are so called "smart quotes", and their UTF-16 hex codes are 201C and 201D.

So to remove them you can use those codes instead of `r'\"'`:

```
.replace('\u201c', '').replace('\u201d', '')
```

But how a problem like this can be solved in general?

You can copy the text directly from the site and save it in a text file with **UTF-16** encoding. Then look at the binary contents of the file, e.g. using `hexdump` command on linux/macOS, find the character codes and convert them to Python strings like this `'\u<4-character hex unicode sequence>'`.

Comment: An even simpler way might be to just _copy_ funny characters from the rendered HTML into your code editor: `.replace('“', '').replace('”', ''))`